# django multiple filters on field

Tags: python, django, django-filter, django-filters

I'm doing a simple filter -

filters.py

```
class TblserversFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(name="servername", lookup_type="exact")

    class Meta:
        model = Tblservers
        fields = ['servername']
```

What I would like to do, if possible, is to have two lookup_types associated with the field.  Specifically I want `exact` AND `contains` and then somehow replace the operator depending on the filter.

`name=serverabc` would be an exact search and `name~abc` will be a fuzzy search.

Answer (score 2):

You could do a  [method_filter](http://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/usage.html#methodfilter) and then prefix your filter queries with different symbols for exact and icontains and other filters that you want at the client side.

Since code is better than a thousand words:

```
exact_prefix = '#'
icontains_prefix = '~'


class TblserversFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.MethodFilter(
            action=name_filter)

    def name_filter(self, value):
        if value:
            value_prefix = value[0]

            if value_prefix == exact_prefix:
                return self.filter(name=value)

            elif value_prefix == icontains_prefix:
                return self.filter(name__icontains=value)

            # this can continue for all the types of filters you want
            else:
                return self.filter(name=value)
        else:
            return self.filter(name=value)

    class Meta:
        model = Tblservers
       fields = ['servername']
```

**EDIT:**

In django-filter 1.0 `MethodFilter` [was replaced with `Filter`'s `method` argument](https://django-filter.readthedocs.io/en/develop/guide/migration.html?highlight=methodfilter#methodfilter-and-filter-action-replaced-by-filter-method). So solution rewritten for v1.0 would be following (not tested):

```
exact_prefix = '#'
icontains_prefix = '~'


class TblserversFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    name = django_filters.CharFilter(
            method='name_filter')

    def name_filter(self, qs, name, value):
        if value:
            value_prefix = value[0]

            if value_prefix == exact_prefix:
                return qs.filter(name=value)

            elif value_prefix == icontains_prefix:
                return qs.filter(name__icontains=value)

            # this can continue for all the types of filters you want
            else:
                return qs.filter(name=value)
        else:
            return qs.filter(name=value)

    class Meta:
        model = Tblservers
       fields = ['servername']
```

Answer (score 1):

First my apologies for the shameless library self-plug.

At some point I was trying to do something similar in django-filters however the solution was much more complex then anticipated. I ended up creating my own library for doing filtering in Django which natively supports the exact functionality you are looking for - [django-url-filter](http://django-url-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/index.html). Its API is very similar to django-filters:

```
from django import forms
from url_filter.filter import Filter
from url_filter.filtersets import ModelFilterSet

class TblserversFilter(FilterSet):
    name = Filter(form_field=forms.CharField(max_length=15), lookups=['exact', 'contains'])

    class Meta(object):
        model = Tblservers
        fields = ['name', 'servername']
```

Note that the URL will look a bit different though:

```
?name=foo  # exact
?name__exact=foo
?name__contains=foo
```

Also you will need to manually call the filter set in order to filter the queryset:

```
fs = TblserversFilter(data=query, queryset=...)
filtered_qs = fs.filter()
```

Syntax of the URL parameters is very similar to Django ORM.
You can look at the docs for more examples. Hopefully it might be of use.

Comment: This looks like what I need however the code you've posted doesn't work with my existing views.  I've replaced the code in my filters.py and I get an error `'TblserversFilter' object has no attribute 'qs'` which makes sense as the qs is in the view not the filter.

Comment: Yes. the internal API does not match django-filter. You will need to manually call the filter API. I plan to add django-filters compatible API to the libs so that usage will be identical and users can migrate quickly.

Comment: thnx.  looking further I actually just made a separate filter on my TblserversFilter so I had a `name__contains = django_filters.CharFilter(name="servername", lookup_type="contains")` as well as a `name = django_filters.CharFilter(name="servername", lookup_type="exact")`

Comment: Yep. That should work. That was one of the reasons I did not like django-filters. You end up adding a field in filterset for each lookup you want supported. If you decide to give django-url-filter a try and find any bugs, please feel free to open tickets in GitHub.